# Is subset of increasing homeomorphisms of $[0,1]$ closed subset in $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $C[0,1]$ be a metric space of continuous function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ with sup-metric

$$d(f,g)=\underset{x\in [0,1]}{sup}|f(x)-g(x)|.$$

Let $H^+[0,1]\subset C[0,1]$ be a subset consisting increasing homeomorphisms of $[0,1]$, i.e. such homeomorphisms $f$ that $f(0)=0$.

> Is the subset $H^+[0,1]$ closed subset of $C[0,1]$?

I tried to prove converse but failed to find some $g\in C[0,1]\setminus H^+[0,1]$ with arbitrary neighborhood intersecting $H^+[0,1]$.

I failed as well to find a sequence of increasing homeomorphisms oof $[0,1]$ converging to an element of $C[0,1]\setminus H^+[0,1]$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod: nice try, but that sequence is not Cauchy with respect to the sup-norm, so that does not prove anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $n\geq 1$, let $f_n$ be the function whose graph goes on straight lines between the points $$(0,0)\\
\left(\frac13,\frac 1{3n}\right)\\
\left(\frac23,1-\frac1{3n}\right)\\(1,1)$$Now see what happens to these functions as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Nice, the limit isn't injective :)